# Insert JSON into SQLite (GSON + Volley)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

came over from this Topic: [Insert Gson Data into Android Sqlite](http://Android%20update%20SQLite%20with%20GSON%20response%20%E2%80%A6%20how%20should%20I%20parse%20nested%20JSON?)

starting from the onResponse of Volley:

```
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        OverallModel itemList;
        itemList = new Gson().fromJson(response,OverallModel[].class);
        helper.insertData(itemList);
```

this is my OverallModel:

```
public class OverallModel {
    public int id;
    public String beschreibung;
    public String datum;
    public String image_link;
    public String location;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBeschreibung() {
        return beschreibung;
    }

    public void setBeschreibung(String beschreibung) {
        this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
    }

... other getters and setters here
```

with a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Event One",
    "beschreibung": "Description here - Skip quot'e's'?",
    "date": "14.01.2017",
    "image_link": "http://google.com/icon.png"
    "location":"location goes here"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Event Two",
    "beschreibung": "Description here - Skip quot'e's'?",
    "date": "16.01.2017",
    "image_link": "http://google.com/icon.png"
    "location":"location goes here"
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

I now need a helper Method to put the data into a SQLite DB, without GSON I did it with this code:

```
JSONArray events = response.getJSONArray("events");
for (int h = 0; h < events.length(); h++) {
String jr_date = c.getString("datum");
String jr_imgurl = c.getString("image_link");
.
.
String SQLiteDataBaseQuery
                                = "INSERT INTO overall_table (id,des,name,date,imgurl,fburl,fbid,entry,open,closed) VALUES('"+id+"', '"+jr_descr+"', '"+jr_name+"', '"+jr_date+"', '"+jr_imgurl+"', '"+jr_fburl+"', '"+jr_fbid+"', '8.0' , '22:00', '3:30');";
                        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQuery);
```

with a DB Helper Class:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TAB_NAME+" ("+table_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
+table_desc+" VARCHAR, "
+ table_name+ " VARCHAR, "
+ table_date+" VARCHAR, "
.
.
+ table_open+" VARCHAR,"
+ table_closed+" VARCHAR)";
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

How do I create the correct Helper Class for my GSON to put the de-serialized data into my Table / DB?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) ORM database

You can easily insert a list of models efficiently.

Comment: I've never heard of that, thank you for the input. But the rest of my uses the sqlite table I'm parsing, can I use this library only to parse the JSON leaving the "access the parsed table" - code untouched? Is it possible for you to make an example for my JSON?